# Group by with multiple properties on single array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have array of objects on which I want to apply groupBy() with two fields. I can achieve group by with single field but not able to achieve with 2 fields.

I want output in following format:

```
{
   data: [
     {
        "name":"que1",
         "image":"img1",
        "data":[
            {
               "name":"que1",
               "title":"title1",
               "description":"desc1",
               "instruction":"inst1",
               "image":"img1",
            },
            {
               "name":"que1",
               "title":"title2",
               "description":"desc1",
               "instruction":"inst1",
               "image":"img1",
            },
            {
               "name":"que1",
               "title":"title3",
               "description":"desc1",
               "instruction":"inst1",
               "image":"img1",
            },
           {
               "name":"que1",
               "title":"title4",
               "description":"desc1",
               "instruction":"inst1",
               "image":"img1",
            }
           ]
     },
    {
       "name":"que1",
         "image":"img1",
        "data":[
            {
               "name":"que1",
               "title":"title1",
               "description":"desc1",
               "instruction":"inst1",
               "image":"img1",
            },
            {
               "name":"que1",
               "title":"title2",
               "description":"desc1",
               "instruction":"inst1",
               "image":"img1",
            }
          ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
_.chain(quesList)
        .groupBy("category","image")
        .map((value, key) => ({ name: key, data: value }))
        .value()
```

Is it possible to achieve this kind of output?

Comment: What's your input (`quesList`)? Have you tried `.groupBy(["category","image"])`? (Note `[` and `]`)

Comment: Yes, @barbsan.. I tried ```.groupBy(["category","image"])``` but not giving me as I want..

Comment: You can use a function for the groupBy iteratee in which you can do whatever you want e.g. item => item.category + "#" + item.image;

Comment: Yes, @GruffBunny, by concatenating I am getting what I want. Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try concatenating them to use as a virtual key for grouping, as you can use a callback as the grouping algo, so just concatenate and return that.

Don't concatenate straight forward, it can have ambiguity problem. (eg: `"AB" + "C"` and `"A" + "BC"` is resulting the same) Use any separator and concatenate.

Just modifying your ans:

```
_.chain(quesList)
        .groupBy(({category,image}) => category + '|' + image)
        .map((value) => ({ name: value[0].name, image: value[0].image, data: value }))
        .value()
```

Each group mast have some value (in a result of group by, otherwise it will not form a group), so you can take the properties from the first object blindly.

Note: Correct properties name which you want to map outside, as I just guessed and placed `name` and `image`